# SharePoint 2013, default site collection dead

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When trying to open my SharePoint, I receive the following:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Date: Wed, 04 Sep 2013 12:29:51 GMT
Connection: close

1. Site Collection does exist
2. Application pool and website is started
3. I have done IIS reset
4. I have done a server reboot
5. Other site collections work on the same Web application
6. I have even tried running the Products and Config wizard again.

Additional Symptoms(SOOOOOOOOOO weird):

When accessing the WFE server with the Farm account used to install the SP 2013 server, the following is MISSING, ***please note when logging in with a different account, the below is present***:

1. SharePoint 15 hive
2. SharePoint windows services
3. SharePoint executable icons, such as Central admin, Products and Config, and SP Powershell

ANY ideas or advice would be great.

Thank you,
JP

Comment: Do you have a firewall in place, such as MS Forefront? Think you might have to publish the web app URL through the firewall to allow it to load on clients.

Comment: I'm guessing your WFE server just doesn't have SharePoint installed, and is also therefore not connected to the farm.

Comment: There is only 1 WFE, and other site collections are working, thus SharePoint has to be installed and connected to the farm.

Comment: Open up IIS and check if the sites are there? The fact that you can't see the folders is a permissions issue.

Comment: Did you ensure that the site collection do exist by checking it in the "View all site collections" in the central admin?

Comment: Did you create a site collection there (at that URL) or restore one from an older version of SharePoint?

Comment: The site are all there, it was a vanilla install, no upgrades, and it has been running for a few month or 2, I dont know what changed

Comment: Yes I did, it does exist

Comment: And what should i do if i cant even get to the administration page getting this error? Other Sharepoint sites (Content e.g.) work except administration page which does not start with that error...

Comment: Please remove content Database and attach again. This has been working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to why my Default site collection was dead. I wrote it all up on my site. 
http://dea.nbird.com.au/2013/09/11/sharepoint-2013-http1-1-200-ok-server-microsoft-iis8-0-connection-close-error/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Afraid it doesn't help very much because, while  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Control Panel> Administrative Tool>Server Manager> Web Server. it contains the log for the reason why its not running. Mostly it is some services that stopped. The log will give exactly the which services have stopped, and go to the services and start that service(usually it's the SecurityToken service. Good luck.